# MYSQL LEFT JOIN results with tables?

Tags: mysql, join

After SELECT a table GROUP BY a field, I get a results, and then I LEFT JOIN the results with a table. Can I do that?

Thankyou!

Comment: Yes, you can :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be, try:

```
Select *
From(
    SELECT *
    FROM myTableOne
    GROUP BY myCol1
) firstTable
LEFT JOIN myTableTwo secondTable ON 
    firstTable.idColumn = secondTable.idColumn
```

Where myTableOne is the group by selection and myTableTwo is the table you want to left join on